# ARCore alternative on Android

Tags: android, location, coordinates, arcore

I'm developing an Android app with Augmented Reality in order to **display points of interests at given location**. I do not need face, plane or object recognition, only placing some points at specific locations (lat/long).
It seems **ARCore on Android only supports few devices**, my customer requires more devices supported as the AR view is the core of the app.
I was wondering if there are **alternatives to ARCore on Android that supports placing points of interest at some coordinates, covering a large number of Android devices**.
Thanks for any tip.

Comment: Also be aware of companies like [Wikitude](https://www.wikitude.com/products/wikitude-sdk/) I would also check various map sdks as [POI in camera demos date back to 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-KWzcyVUww) Behavior limited by have a calibrated compass, else device doesn't know where it is facing. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is this location based AR framework for Android: https://github.com/bitstars/droidar

However it hasn't been maintained for quite a long time. You can also look at vuforia, however it's not free:
https://developer.vuforia.com/

Comment: Thanks, yes I've seen droidAR but no longer maintained from 7 years.
Will check vuforia.